# Training on skewed dataset

Tags: keras, lstm, overfitting

I have a problem of multi class classification and I'm using a simple 2-Layer Bi-directional LSTM with **keras**.

The model in a simple form:

```
Bidirectional LSTM (64)
Bidirectional LSTM (64)
Dense (128)
Activation Sigmoid
Dense (14)
Activation Softmax
```

I have a **raw** and **skewed** dataset so I'm doing all the pre-processing myself to balance it.

- Firstly, I replicated the original data and produced 3*OriginalData
  to produce more examples of certain classes that weren't represented.
- Then I performed classification and the loss and accuracy history are
  depicted below for both training and validation sets

[image: Using Small Dataset]

Accuracy built up after 25 epochs, but loss had major variations, so I decided to replicate more of my data so I produced 10*OriginalData, and performed classification again.

Now my loss and accuracy behaved so much worse.

[image: Using Big Dataset]

**My question is** whether the problem lies in my model, or at the replication of data. Is it possible for a model to work well with less data but not so good when it has so many? Or maybe I'm causing it to overfit by providing over-replicated data?

**Note:** By replicating data, I don't mean duplicating, but because I work with *audio data*, I play with different pitch shifts.

Answer (score 3):

It could be your model or your data. You need to perform the experiment of changing your model (while holding data constant) to isolate the causal reason.

Yes - models can get worse with more data. One of the primary reasons is models often have a limited capacity to learn. Simple models can only successfully model simple relationships. Again - if you fit a more complex model, you'll start to understand the mechanism that could be causing this observation.